# Broadcast receiver distinguishing call reason based on action name of intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, intentfilter

I am having a problem with my application's broadcast receiver.

I have a situation where I wan the broadcast receiver to be called for 3 different reasons, first phone state changed, second, based on a timer, and third on boot complete.  And then according to the reason by which the broadcast receiver was called I want to be able to do some stuff.

below is my android manifest of my receiver:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.example.mobileraptor.MyPhoneListener" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <action android:name="com.example.mobileraptor.TimerTriggered" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and the following is where i declare my TimerTriggered intent:

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.example.mobileraptor.TimerTriggered"), 0 );
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));

    manager.setInexactRepeating( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR , pintent );
```

The problem is that once the application wants to boot it crashes.  but if I comment the line :
action android:name="com.example.mobileraptor.TimerTriggered
then my application is fine.

what is wrong with the action name that I have defined.

Comment: logcat:
06-24 19:20:35.319: W/dalvikvm(278): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-24 19:20:35.349: E/AndroidRuntime(278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 19:20:35.349: E/AndroidRuntime(278): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.mobileraptor.MyPhoneListener: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.mobileraptor.MyPhoneListener

Comment: i fixed the problem. it was a stupid mistake on my part, the name of the receiver on my XML file did not match the class name of my receiver.